# how to automatically slide images using Timer in swift.

Tags: ios, timer, uiimageview, swift4

I want to use below lines but where should I write it?

```
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(function), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you want to achieve. If you want that slider automatically start when app loads, then put it in viewDidLoad().

If you want to start slider when you press some button, then you need to put this code inside the @IBAction function for that button.

Note: @objc function which is determining work of the slider is written separately, like in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

```
     var i=Int()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(imageChange), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

@objc func imageChange(){
    self.imageView.image=images[i]
    if i<images.count-1{
        i+=1
    }
    else{
        i=0
    }
}
```